# Server freeze with "rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks"

Tags: linux, kernel, server-crashes

My web server is crashing several times a week.
I see errors in syslog but I can't find a solution.
I tried changing kernel to older or newer versions but no difference. I moved everything to a new machine, but problem is still there. This has to be software related.
Any idea ?

```
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.535784] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.535804] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 29 at /build/buildd/linux-3.13.0/net/sched/sch_generic.c:264 dev_watchdog+0x276/0x280()
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.535810] NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth0 (igb): transmit queue 6 timed out
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.535814] Modules linked in: nfnetlink_queue nfnetlink_log nfnetlink bluetooth binfmt_misc xt_tcpudp nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 iptable_filter ip_tables nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 xt_conntrack nf_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables x_tables ast ttm drm_kms_helper coretemp drm kvm_intel kvm gpio_ich syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul i2c_ismt ghash_clmulni_intel shpchp joydev aesni_intel lpc_ich aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper mac_hid ablk_helper ipmi_si cryptd lp parport btrfs libcrc32c raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq raid1 igb raid0 hid_generic i2c_algo_bit dca multipath usbhid ptp ahci hid linear libahci pps_core
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.535928] CPU: 1 PID: 29 Comm: ksoftirqd/1 Not tainted 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.535932] Hardware name: Supermicro A1SAi/A1SAi, BIOS 1.0b 11/06/2013
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.535936]  0000000000000009 ffff880469655c80 ffffffff81715a64 ffff880469655cc8
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.535948]  ffff880469655cb8 ffffffff810676bd 0000000000000006 ffff880464258000
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.535957]  ffff880469002940 0000000000000008 0000000000000001 ffff880469655d18
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.535966] Call Trace:
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.535980]  [<ffffffff81715a64>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.535990]  [<ffffffff810676bd>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.535998]  [<ffffffff8106772c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536007]  [<ffffffff810a2d34>] ? update_curr+0xe4/0x180
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536020]  [<ffffffff8163ae76>] dev_watchdog+0x276/0x280
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536029]  [<ffffffff8163ac00>] ? dev_graft_qdisc+0x80/0x80
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536037]  [<ffffffff81074226>] call_timer_fn+0x36/0x100
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536046]  [<ffffffff8163ac00>] ? dev_graft_qdisc+0x80/0x80
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536054]  [<ffffffff810751bf>] run_timer_softirq+0x1ef/0x2f0
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536063]  [<ffffffff8106caec>] __do_softirq+0xec/0x2c0
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536072]  [<ffffffff8106ccf0>] run_ksoftirqd+0x30/0x50
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536080]  [<ffffffff8109263f>] smpboot_thread_fn+0xff/0x1b0
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536088]  [<ffffffff81092540>] ? SyS_setgroups+0x1a0/0x1a0
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536097]  [<ffffffff8108b312>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536106]  [<ffffffff8108b240>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1d0/0x1d0
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536115]  [<ffffffff8172637c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536124]  [<ffffffff8108b240>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1d0/0x1d0
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536129] ---[ end trace c24a078afb41bdb5 ]---
Apr 30 18:11:16 kronos kernel: [751015.536167] igb 0000:00:14.0 eth0: Reset adapter
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767039] INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks: { 4} (detected by 0, t=15002 jiffies, g=9072572, c=9072571, q=0)
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767263] sending NMI to all CPUs:
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767275] NMI backtrace for cpu 0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767283] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G        W    3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767287] Hardware name: Supermicro A1SAi/A1SAi, BIOS 1.0b 11/06/2013
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767293] task: ffffffff81c15480 ti: ffffffff81c00000 task.ti: ffffffff81c00000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767298] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8136c597>]  [<ffffffff8136c597>] __bitmap_empty+0x17/0x80
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767312] RSP: 0018:ffff88047fc03df0  EFLAGS: 00000006
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767316] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000002710 RCX: 0000000000000004
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767321] RDX: 0000000000000c00 RSI: 0000000000000100 RDI: ffffffff81d121a0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767326] RBP: ffff88047fc03df0 R08: 0000000000000082 R09: 00000000000003d3
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767330] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffff88047fc03b2e R12: ffffffff81c4e140
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767335] R13: ffffffff81d12620 R14: ffffffff81c4e140 R15: 0000000000000000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767341] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88047fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767345] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767350] CR2: 00000000013b3000 CR3: 0000000001c0e000 CR4: 00000000001007f0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767354] Stack:
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767358]  ffff88047fc03e08 ffffffff81044c61 ffff88047fc0e800 ffff88047fc03e60
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767369]  ffffffff810cab21 ffffffff81c4e140 ffffffff00000004 0000000000000000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767379]  0000000000000001 ffffffff81c15480 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767388] Call Trace:
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767392]  <IRQ> 
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767397]  [<ffffffff81044c61>] arch_trigger_all_cpu_backtrace+0x81/0xb0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767414]  [<ffffffff810cab21>] rcu_check_callbacks+0x631/0x650
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767425]  [<ffffffff81076217>] update_process_times+0x47/0x70
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767434]  [<ffffffff810d5be5>] tick_sched_handle.isra.17+0x25/0x60
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767442]  [<ffffffff810d5c61>] tick_sched_timer+0x41/0x60
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767451]  [<ffffffff8108e537>] __run_hrtimer+0x77/0x1d0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767460]  [<ffffffff810d5c20>] ? tick_sched_handle.isra.17+0x60/0x60
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767468]  [<ffffffff8108ed3f>] hrtimer_interrupt+0xef/0x230
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767479]  [<ffffffff81043087>] local_apic_timer_interrupt+0x37/0x60
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767489]  [<ffffffff817287ff>] smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x3f/0x60
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767498]  [<ffffffff8172719d>] apic_timer_interrupt+0x6d/0x80
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767502]  <EOI> 
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767506]  [<ffffffff815c9582>] ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x52/0xc0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767523]  [<ffffffff815c96a9>] cpuidle_idle_call+0xb9/0x1f0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767533]  [<ffffffff8101ceae>] arch_cpu_idle+0xe/0x30
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767542]  [<ffffffff810beb85>] cpu_startup_entry+0xc5/0x290
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767552]  [<ffffffff81703f37>] rest_init+0x77/0x80
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767562]  [<ffffffff81d34f70>] start_kernel+0x438/0x443
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767571]  [<ffffffff81d34941>] ? repair_env_string+0x5c/0x5c
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767580]  [<ffffffff81d34120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767589]  [<ffffffff81d345ee>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767598]  [<ffffffff81d34733>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x143/0x152
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767602] Code: 40 c7 04 24 10 00 00 00 48 89 44 24 10 e8 42 ff ff ff c9 c3 8d 4e 3f 85 f6 55 0f 49 ce 48 89 e5 c1 f9 06 85 c9 7e 61 48 83 3f 00 <75> 57 48 8d 47 08 31 d2 eb 12 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 48 83 c0 08 
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767682] NMI backtrace for cpu 1
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767692] CPU: 1 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/1 Tainted: G        W    3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767697] Hardware name: Supermicro A1SAi/A1SAi, BIOS 1.0b 11/06/2013
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767703] task: ffff8804696217f0 ti: ffff88046962a000 task.ti: ffff88046962a000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767707] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff813dfd78>]  [<ffffffff813dfd78>] intel_idle+0xd8/0x140
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767719] RSP: 0018:ffff88046962be28  EFLAGS: 00000046
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767723] RAX: 0000000000000051 RBX: 0000000000000040 RCX: 0000000000000001
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767728] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffffff81c93220 RDI: 0000000000000001
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767733] RBP: ffff88046962be50 R08: ffff88047fc512cc R09: 0000000000002018
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767737] R10: 00000000ffffffff R11: 000000000000f80b R12: 0000000000000002
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767742] R13: 0000000000000051 R14: 0000000000000006 R15: ffffffff81c932e8
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767747] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88047fc40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767752] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767757] CR2: 00007f71205d2220 CR3: 0000000001c0e000 CR4: 00000000001007e0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767761] Stack:
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767764]  000000016962be50 ffff88047fc5b000 ffffffff81c93220 0002aa899e46daf8
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767775]  0000000000000002 ffff88046962be88 ffffffff815c9570 ffff88046962bf38
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767784]  ffff88047fc5b000 0000000000000002 0000000000000001 ffffffff81c93220
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767794] Call Trace:
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767805]  [<ffffffff815c9570>] cpuidle_enter_state+0x40/0xc0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767815]  [<ffffffff815c96a9>] cpuidle_idle_call+0xb9/0x1f0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767824]  [<ffffffff8101ceae>] arch_cpu_idle+0xe/0x30
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767832]  [<ffffffff810beb85>] cpu_startup_entry+0xc5/0x290
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767841]  [<ffffffff81040fc8>] start_secondary+0x218/0x2c0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767845] Code: 48 89 d1 48 2d c8 1f 00 00 0f 01 c8 0f ae f0 65 48 8b 04 25 f0 c7 00 00 48 8b 80 38 e0 ff ff a8 08 75 08 b1 01 4c 89 e8 0f 01 c9 <85> 1d 9a 34 8b 00 75 0e 48 8d 75 dc bf 05 00 00 00 e8 12 39 cf 
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767926] NMI backtrace for cpu 2
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767940] CPU: 2 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/2 Tainted: G        W    3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767945] Hardware name: Supermicro A1SAi/A1SAi, BIOS 1.0b 11/06/2013
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767951] task: ffff880469622fe0 ti: ffff88046962c000 task.ti: ffff88046962c000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.767969] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff813dfd78>]  [<ffffffff813dfd78>] intel_idle+0xd8/0x140
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768005] RSP: 0018:ffff88046962de28  EFLAGS: 00000046
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768023] RAX: 0000000000000051 RBX: 0000000000000040 RCX: 0000000000000001
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768041] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffffff81c93220 RDI: 0000000001c0e000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768057] RBP: ffff88046962de50 R08: ffff88047fc912d0 R09: 0000000000000018
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768075] R10: 000000000003a0c3 R11: 0000000000078cd7 R12: 0000000000000002
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768091] R13: 0000000000000051 R14: 0000000000000006 R15: ffffffff81c932e8
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768109] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88047fc80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768128] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768146] CR2: 00007ffa85dce090 CR3: 0000000001c0e000 CR4: 00000000001007e0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768163] Stack:
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768179]  000000026962de50 ffff88047fc9b000 ffffffff81c93220 0002aa89978add53
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768242]  0000000000000002 ffff88046962de88 ffffffff815c9570 ffff88046962df38
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768268]  ffff88047fc9b000 0000000000000002 0000000000000002 ffffffff81c93220
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768277] Call Trace:
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768292]  [<ffffffff815c9570>] cpuidle_enter_state+0x40/0xc0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768301]  [<ffffffff815c96a9>] cpuidle_idle_call+0xb9/0x1f0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768312]  [<ffffffff8101ceae>] arch_cpu_idle+0xe/0x30
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768321]  [<ffffffff810beb85>] cpu_startup_entry+0xc5/0x290
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768331]  [<ffffffff81040fc8>] start_secondary+0x218/0x2c0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768335] Code: 48 89 d1 48 2d c8 1f 00 00 0f 01 c8 0f ae f0 65 48 8b 04 25 f0 c7 00 00 48 8b 80 38 e0 ff ff a8 08 75 08 b1 01 4c 89 e8 0f 01 c9 <85> 1d 9a 34 8b 00 75 0e 48 8d 75 dc bf 05 00 00 00 e8 12 39 cf 
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768415] NMI backtrace for cpu 3
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768422] INFO: NMI handler (arch_trigger_all_cpu_backtrace_handler) took too long to run: 1.058 msecs
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768435] CPU: 3 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/3 Tainted: G        W    3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768439] Hardware name: Supermicro A1SAi/A1SAi, BIOS 1.0b 11/06/2013
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768444] task: ffff8804696247d0 ti: ffff88046962e000 task.ti: ffff88046962e000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768449] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff813dfd78>]  [<ffffffff813dfd78>] intel_idle+0xd8/0x140
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768460] RSP: 0018:ffff88046962fe28  EFLAGS: 00000046
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768464] RAX: 0000000000000051 RBX: 0000000000000040 RCX: 0000000000000001
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768469] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffffff81c93220 RDI: 0000000000000003
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768473] RBP: ffff88046962fe50 R08: ffff88047fcd12d0 R09: 0000000000000018
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768478] R10: 000000000001865d R11: 0000000000079f7d R12: 0000000000000002
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768482] R13: 0000000000000051 R14: 0000000000000006 R15: ffffffff81c932e8
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768488] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88047fcc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768493] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768497] CR2: 00007fff867d9718 CR3: 0000000001c0e000 CR4: 00000000001007e0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768501] Stack:
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768505]  000000036962fe50 ffff88047fcdb000 ffffffff81c93220 0002aa899a7643cc
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768515]  0000000000000002 ffff88046962fe88 ffffffff815c9570 ffff88046962ff38
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768525]  ffff88047fcdb000 0000000000000002 0000000000000003 ffffffff81c93220
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768534] Call Trace:
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768546]  [<ffffffff815c9570>] cpuidle_enter_state+0x40/0xc0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768555]  [<ffffffff815c96a9>] cpuidle_idle_call+0xb9/0x1f0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768564]  [<ffffffff8101ceae>] arch_cpu_idle+0xe/0x30
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768572]  [<ffffffff810beb85>] cpu_startup_entry+0xc5/0x290
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768591]  [<ffffffff81040fc8>] start_secondary+0x218/0x2c0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768608] Code: 48 89 d1 48 2d c8 1f 00 00 0f 01 c8 0f ae f0 65 48 8b 04 25 f0 c7 00 00 48 8b 80 38 e0 ff ff a8 08 75 08 b1 01 4c 89 e8 0f 01 c9 <85> 1d 9a 34 8b 00 75 0e 48 8d 75 dc bf 05 00 00 00 e8 12 39 cf 
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768758] NMI backtrace for cpu 6
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768765] INFO: NMI handler (arch_trigger_all_cpu_backtrace_handler) took too long to run: 1.399 msecs
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768779] CPU: 6 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/6 Tainted: G        W    3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768784] Hardware name: Supermicro A1SAi/A1SAi, BIOS 1.0b 11/06/2013
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768790] task: ffff8804696397f0 ti: ffff880469634000 task.ti: ffff880469634000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768794] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff813dfd78>]  [<ffffffff813dfd78>] intel_idle+0xd8/0x140
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768821] RSP: 0018:ffff880469635e28  EFLAGS: 00000046
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768837] RAX: 0000000000000051 RBX: 0000000000000040 RCX: 0000000000000001
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768842] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffffff81c93220 RDI: 0000000001c0e000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768846] RBP: ffff880469635e50 R08: ffff88047fd912d4 R09: 0000000000000018
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768851] R10: 00000000000590e8 R11: 00000000000cd1e5 R12: 0000000000000002
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768855] R13: 0000000000000051 R14: 0000000000000006 R15: ffffffff81c932e8
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768861] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88047fd80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768866] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768871] CR2: 00007fcae77e6fe0 CR3: 0000000001c0e000 CR4: 00000000001007e0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768889] Stack:
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768903]  0000000669635e50 ffff88047fd9b000 ffffffff81c93220 0002aa898db88408
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768915]  0000000000000002 ffff880469635e88 ffffffff815c9570 ffff880469635f38
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768925]  ffff88047fd9b000 0000000000000002 0000000000000006 ffffffff81c93220
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768934] Call Trace:
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768959]  [<ffffffff815c9570>] cpuidle_enter_state+0x40/0xc0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768972]  [<ffffffff815c96a9>] cpuidle_idle_call+0xb9/0x1f0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768983]  [<ffffffff8101ceae>] arch_cpu_idle+0xe/0x30
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.768999]  [<ffffffff810beb85>] cpu_startup_entry+0xc5/0x290
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769009]  [<ffffffff81040fc8>] start_secondary+0x218/0x2c0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769021] Code: 48 89 d1 48 2d c8 1f 00 00 0f 01 c8 0f ae f0 65 48 8b 04 25 f0 c7 00 00 48 8b 80 38 e0 ff ff a8 08 75 08 b1 01 4c 89 e8 0f 01 c9 <85> 1d 9a 34 8b 00 75 0e 48 8d 75 dc bf 05 00 00 00 e8 12 39 cf 
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769102] NMI backtrace for cpu 7
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769109] INFO: NMI handler (arch_trigger_all_cpu_backtrace_handler) took too long to run: 1.736 msecs
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769122] CPU: 7 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/7 Tainted: G        W    3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769127] Hardware name: Supermicro A1SAi/A1SAi, BIOS 1.0b 11/06/2013
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769132] task: ffff88046963afe0 ti: ffff880469636000 task.ti: ffff880469636000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769137] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff813dfd78>]  [<ffffffff813dfd78>] intel_idle+0xd8/0x140
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769156] RSP: 0018:ffff880469637e28  EFLAGS: 00000046
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769173] RAX: 0000000000000051 RBX: 0000000000000040 RCX: 0000000000000001
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769183] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffffff81c93220 RDI: 0000000000000007
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769188] RBP: ffff880469637e50 R08: ffff88047fdd12c8 R09: 0000000000000018
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769192] R10: 0000000000165604 R11: 00000000001dd88c R12: 0000000000000002
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769197] R13: 0000000000000051 R14: 0000000000000006 R15: ffffffff81c932e8
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769202] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88047fdc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769207] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769212] CR2: 00007f40d680f000 CR3: 0000000001c0e000 CR4: 00000000001007e0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769215] Stack:
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769219]  0000000769637e50 ffff88047fddb000 ffffffff81c93220 0002aa893339d20a
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769230]  0000000000000002 ffff880469637e88 ffffffff815c9570 ffff880469637f38
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769239]  ffff88047fddb000 0000000000000002 0000000000000007 ffffffff81c93220
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769276] Call Trace:
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769291]  [<ffffffff815c9570>] cpuidle_enter_state+0x40/0xc0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769300]  [<ffffffff815c96a9>] cpuidle_idle_call+0xb9/0x1f0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769309]  [<ffffffff8101ceae>] arch_cpu_idle+0xe/0x30
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769318]  [<ffffffff810beb85>] cpu_startup_entry+0xc5/0x290
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769327]  [<ffffffff81040fc8>] start_secondary+0x218/0x2c0
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769344] Code: 48 89 d1 48 2d c8 1f 00 00 0f 01 c8 0f ae f0 65 48 8b 04 25 f0 c7 00 00 48 8b 80 38 e0 ff ff a8 08 75 08 b1 01 4c 89 e8 0f 01 c9 <85> 1d 9a 34 8b 00 75 0e 48 8d 75 dc bf 05 00 00 00 e8 12 39 cf 
Apr 30 18:12:09 kronos kernel: [751068.769426] INFO: NMI handler (arch_trigger_all_cpu_backtrace_handler) took too long to run: 2.055 msecs
Apr 30 18:15:09 kronos kernel: [751248.933567] INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks: { 4} (detected by 0, t=60007 jiffies, g=9072572, c=9072571, q=0)
Apr 30 18:15:09 kronos kernel: [751248.933674] sending NMI to all CPUs:
Apr 30 18:15:09 kronos kernel: [751248.933681] NMI backtrace for cpu 0
Apr 30 18:15:09 kronos kernel: [751248.933685] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G        W    3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu
```

Comment: Does http://plus10.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/netdev-watchdog-eth0-transmit-queue-0.html help ?

Comment: I tried another similar solution : "nosmp". I'm waiting a few days to see if it solves the issue. I'll try pcie_aspm=off however because nosmp causes the server to use only one core so that's not optimal. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by disabling SMP (added "nosmp" parameter in Grub conf).
The server is running fine now.

Comment: That's going to decrease the server performance. But that is of course better than crashing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error suddently. There were 3 options that was helping me to boot (one at the time):

- `nosmp`
- `nomodeset`
- `dis_ucode_ldr`